# Proxy Settings per Machine not working on windows server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, proxy, group-policy, internet

i have a very interesting problem and would appreciate any help for it. In my scenario i have scripts which bring up a VM inside a domain. Now i want to enable internet access for all the VM's and they go through a proxy. I interact with the VM's using remote sessions and use the credentials of a user which belogs to the domain administrator group.

Now problem is that, i create VM's on the fly and destroy them as well,and the scripts i run during their lifetime require internet access on them.So i cannot statically set the proxy settings thus i used the option of Active Directory Group Policy Management. I initially used the "User Configuration" option and set the proxy, which worked like a charm when ever i log inside the machine.

However it doesn't work if i use to remote login to the machine with an account which has not yet logged in to the machine. So i used this [link](http://wiki.ledhed.net/index.php/Set_Proxy_Server_with_Group_Policy) to configure it to work on Per Machine, the group policy has worked fine and it reflects in the browser too.

But i am not able to resolve any dns name like http://www.google.com or any internet based site. Any idea what i can do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what that article was telling you to do (I only glanced at it) but the way to apply users policies defined on the computer is to use group policy loopback.  That being said if you have name resolution issues, that is not a proxy issue,  that's a DNS issue

Answer (score 0):

The link provided is just to set proxy on all users, whoever log in. System process won't be able to authenticate as they aren't user.

How do you establish remote session ? You may need to load the profile, so the proxy setting is loaded.

During your script, you can use netsh to force proxy:

```
Netsh winhttp  set proxy proxy-server="http=myproxy"
```